# CSV file filled in data adapter is empty or not

Tags: csv

private DataTable GetDataFromCSV()
        {

```
        System.Data.DataTable dtExecChanges = new System.Data.DataTable("exec_changes");

        string dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(sInputFileName);          

        using (OleDbConnection cn =
            new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" +
                    "Data Source=" + dirName + ";" +
                    "Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\""))
        {
            // Open the connection 
            cn.Open();

            // Set up the adapter 
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter =
                new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + (sInputFileName.Substring(sInputFileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1)), cn))
            {                    
                adapter.Fill(dtExecChanges);
            }

            cn.Close();
        }
```

When I fill my data table dtExecChanges it will error coz my CSV file is empty.
Is there a way to chck is the select query is actually fetching any rows b4 filling by data table??